# Add two different types of Charts to Excel and Format them

Tags: excel, vba, charts, formatting

I have a chart that is composed of two main things.

The first is a loop that creates a bunch of series based on values. Each of these series is an XY Scatter with Lines. Each of these Lines is coloured based on conditions using the `Vlookup` function in Excel. The first thing I need to correct is the `Case` part because it doesn't like the first instance of G. This only occurs when I have added the second chart.

The next thing I want is to create an XY Scatter with another Range, then apply Custom Data Labels to only those points. I can change the type of Chart the Series plots by using the answer below, which has been updated.

```
    Dim age1 As Variant
    Dim age2 As Variant
    Dim per1 As Variant
    Dim per2 As Variant
    Dim id as Variant
    Dim mp as Range
    Dim yd as Range
    id = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Value2
    age1 = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Value2
    age2 = Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Value2
    per1 = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Value2
    per2 = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Value2
    Set mp = Range(Range("J2"), Range("J2").End(xlDown))
    Set yd= Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))

    ln = UBound(id) - LBound(id) + 1

    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart

        With cht
            .ChartArea.ClearContents 'Clears the chart so a new one can be created
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines 'Defines the Chart as a Scatter with Lines
            For i = 1 To ln 'First Thing that creates many series
                xdata = Array(age1(i, 1), age2(i, 1))
                ydata = Array(per1(i, 1), per2(i, 1))
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(i).XValues = xdata
                .SeriesCollection(i).Values = ydata
                .SeriesCollection(i).Name = id(i, 1)
            Next i

            'Orginal method: .ChartType = xlXYScatter 
               .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
               .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count).XValues = mp
               .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count).Values = yd
               .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count).Name = "Series"
               'New Method
               .SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count).ChartType = xlXYScatter

        End With
'end of creating charts

        Set drng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown) 'For the Vlookup
        With ActiveSheet
            For Each xycht In .ChartObjects
                For Each mysrs In xycht.Chart.SeriesCollection
                    mysrs.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
                    lnum = Application.VLookup(mysrs.Name, drng, 2, 0) 'This fails the first instance with G as a Type Mismatch Error.
'                    Select Case lnum
'                        Case "G"
'                            lColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
'                        Case "D"
'                            lColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
'                        Case "M"
'                            lColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
'                        Case "A"
'                            lColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
'                        Case Else
'                            lColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'                    End Select
'                    mysrs.MarkerBackgroundColor = lColor
'                    mysrs.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
'                    mysrs.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
'                    mysrs.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = lColor
                Next
                Set mypts = ws.ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(SeriesCollection.Count).Points(1).Apply 'This fails cause it needs an Object
                mypts(mypts.Count).ApplyDataLabels

                    With mypts(mypts.Count).DataLabel
                        .ShowSeriesName = False
                        .ShowCategoryName = False
                        .ShowValue = False 'I need this tonot show Values, but my own Values.
                        ' optional parameters
                        .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
                        .Font.Name = "Helvetica"
                        .Font.Size = 10
                        .Font.Bold = False
                    End With
            Next
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ChartType property of the Series object...

```
.SeriesCollection(.SeriesCollection.Count).ChartType = xlXYScatter
```

Comment: Okay. That is a part of it.

Comment: `Application.Vlookup` returns an error when no match is found.  If so, you'll get a type mismatch error in your `Select Case` statement.  Maybe there should always be a match.  In which case, you'll need to make the necessary adjustments.  Otherwise, you can test for an error with `If IsError(lnum) Then`, and then take the appropriate actions.

Comment: I was able to use a On Error GoTo option to set the color elsewhere. I now need to find a way to set that color to transparent. Why doesn't vba come with a `rgba`

Comment: First, I should have said that `Application.Vlookup` returns a **_non-breaking_** error.  So you won't be able to test using `On Error GoTo`.  You'll need to use `IsError`.

Comment: Secondly, to set the transparency, you'll need to specify a percentage.  For example, to set it at 20% -->  `mysrs.Format.Line.Transparency = 0.2`.

Comment: I only need to apply to a certain series. Also, I have tried to apply that to my certain series, outside my With statement, but it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: You can test for the specified series within your `For Each mysrs/Next` loop.

Comment: I tried and still nothing:                                                                                  
          `If mysrs.Name = "Series" Then`
                       `mysrs.Format.Point.Visible = msoFalse`
                    `End If`

Comment: Are you trying to set the transparency for the series or the point?

Comment: A Single Series.

Comment: Then it should be `If mysrs.Name = "Series" Then mysrs.Format.Line.Transparency = 0.2`.  Change the percentage as desired.

Comment: Okay. That still doesn't work. Nothing changes. When I try to click on the chart and do it manually, I see the name Series as a Series, but when I click edit, the Name of it disappears in the boxes.

Comment: Do you want to set the transparency or do you simply want to set the Visible property to False?

Comment: that worked. Or at least that thought process worked.